# Calling class gives error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following class:

```
class CoreDataController {
@FetchRequest(
        entity: Meals.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Meals.meal_type, ascending: true),
        ]
    ) var meal: FetchedResults<Meals>
}
```

and I'm calling it here:

```
struct itemListView: View {

private var mealData = CoreDataController()

var body: some View {

        List {
            ForEach(mealData.meal, id: \.self) { language in
                Button(action: {
                    print("\(language)")
                }) {
                    Text("\(language.meal_type ?? "Anonymous")")
                }

            }
        }
```

It compiles but it gives me an error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@FetchRequest` is View dynamic value property wrapper and expects `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)`, which can be injected only in View, so the solution would be to put your fetch request construction into view, where it is expected to be.

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context

@FetchRequest(
        entity: Meals.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Meals.meal_type, ascending: true),
        ]
    ) var meal: FetchedResults<Meals>

var body: some View {

        List {
            ForEach(meal, id: \.self) { language in

        // .. your other code
```

Comment: What if I want to define that `@FetchRequest` on another file? Such as CoreDataModel? Is the only solution defining the same thing every time on the views?

Comment: @Spyky, then you need to use NSFetchRequest instead.